# How to detect that django is being called with "manage migrate/syncdb"

Tags: python, django

I have a django codebase, and in most usecases I start it either with:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Or by running a python file which does this:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

However, I need to not perform some operations in apps.py if django has been started with the "manage migrate" or "manage syncdb" options.

How can I detect the manage arguments within apps.py?

Comment: Sounds like you should avoid this altogether. Make the database operations a separate operation, like migrations.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but for my current usecase I would like to do it like this.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I have edited the question.

Comment: One hacky way is to override `AppConfig.ready()` and inside the method, look at the values of `sys.argv`, in particular `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.